# identify non-countable loops in LLVM

Tags: llvm

How can I identify if a loop is countable or not in LLVM? Is there some library function that can be directly used?

Comment: By "countable", I believe you mean "counted".

Comment: By "countable" I really meant "countable". A countable loop has a trip count which can be decided at run time just before the loop starts. That is, the trip count is not decided by the loop body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `hasLoopInvariantBackedgeTakenCount` on `ScalarEvolution`.  See http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ScalarEvolution.html#aecd7aba4460358813feef37d71d5024e .

(If that isn't what you are looking for, please clarify.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this function. I've missed it while reading doxygen, prog-manual, llvm passes. :) Scalar Evolution is very useful for loop analysis :).